# eb delete not recognised by AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm in a virtualenv. I installed `awsebcli` like so: `pip install awsebcli`.

I then did `eb init -p python3.4 django-tutorial` and it said `Application django-tutorial has been created.`. I want to now delete this application. I tried doing `eb delete` but it says

```
usage: eb (sub-commands ...) [options ...] {arguments ...}
eb: error: unrecognized arguments: delete
```

I then tried `eb delete -a django-tutorial` and it said

```
usage: eb (sub-commands ...) [options ...] {arguments ...}
eb: error: unrecognized arguments: delete -a django-tutorial
```

I then just typed `eb` and "delete" was not one of the listed commands. These were the commands listed:

```
  abort        Cancels an environment update or deployment.
  appversion   Listing and managing application versions
  clone        Clones an environment.
  codesource   Configures the code source for the EB CLI to use by default.
  config       Modify an environment's configuration. Use subcommands to manage saved configurations.
  console      Opens the environment in the AWS Elastic Beanstalk Management Console.
  create       Creates a new environment.
  deploy       Deploys your source code to the environment.
  events       Gets recent events.
  health       Shows detailed environment health.
  init         Initializes your directory with the EB CLI. Creates the application.
  labs         Extra experimental commands.
  list         Lists all environments.
  local        Runs commands on your local machine.
  logs         Gets recent logs.
  open         Opens the application URL in a browser.
  platform     Manages platforms.
  printenv     Shows the environment variables.
  restore      Restores a terminated environment.
  scale        Changes the number of running instances.
  setenv       Sets environment variables.
  ssh          Opens the SSH client to connect to an instance.
  status       Gets environment information and status.
  swap         Swaps two environment CNAMEs with each other.
  terminate    Terminates the environment.
  upgrade      Updates the environment to the most recent platform version.
  use          Sets default environment.
```

How do I delete the application I initialised and how come eb is not recognising delete as a command?

Edit: Just noticed `eb stop` doesn't exist either but from this link:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/delete.html

`eb stop` and `eb delete` should both exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `eb terminate --all` to delete the application, and make sure you're looking at the current [EB documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-terminate.html).

Comment: Ah, this worked! Any idea though why `eb delete` and `eb stop` are not recognised?

Comment: The documentation page you linked to is out-of-date and refers to an old version of the CLI.